# Clean nulls from query pivot table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following dataset as an example in MySql engine version 5.x

```
+-----------+------------+
| name      | occupation |
+-----------+------------+
| Samantha  | Doctor     |
| Julia     | Actor      |
| Maria     | Actor      |
| Meera     | Singer     |
| Ashely    | Professor  |
| Ketty     | Professor  |
| Christeen | Professor  |
| Jane      | Actor      |
| Jenny     | Doctor     |
| Priya     | Singer     |
+-----------+------------+
```

I would like pivot the Occupation column in table so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath 
its corresponding Occupation. The output column headers should be Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor, respectively.

I try this

```
SELECT CASE occupation WHEN 'Doctor' THEN name END AS Doctor,
       CASE occupation WHEN 'Professor' THEN name END AS Professor,
       CASE occupation WHEN 'Singer' THEN name END AS Singer,
       CASE occupation WHEN 'Actor' THEN name END AS Actor
FROM occupations;
```

output

```
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
| Doctor   | Professor | Singer | Actor |
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
| NULL     | NULL      | NULL   | Jane  |
| NULL     | NULL      | NULL   | Julia |
| NULL     | NULL      | NULL   | Maria |
| NULL     | NULL      | Meera  | NULL  |
| NULL     | NULL      | Priya  | NULL  |
| NULL     | Ashely    | NULL   | NULL  |
| NULL     | Christeen | NULL   | NULL  |
| NULL     | Ketty     | NULL   | NULL  |
| Jenny    | NULL      | NULL   | NULL  |
| Samantha | NULL      | NULL   | NULL  |
+----------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

but I would like this output

```
Doctor   Professor  Singer Actor
Jenny    Ashley     Meera  Jane
Samantha Christeen  Priya  Julia
NULL     Ketty      NULL   Maria
```

I am jammed with this, any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: Formatting is better done in the app language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  You need aggregation, but have nothing to aggregate on.  For that, you need a row number:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE occupation WHEN 'Doctor' THEN name END) AS Doctor,
       MAX(CASE occupation WHEN 'Professor' THEN name END) AS Professor,
       MAX(CASE occupation WHEN 'Singer' THEN name END) AS Singer,
       MAX(CASE occupation WHEN 'Actor' THEN name END) AS Actor
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation ORDER BY occupation) as seqnum
      FROM occupations o
     ) o
GROUP BY seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f6626f9361591d4ec90feea18e6f46c) is a db<>fiddle, illustrating that the above works.

EDIT:

In older versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE occupation WHEN 'Doctor' THEN name END) AS Doctor,
       MAX(CASE occupation WHEN 'Professor' THEN name END) AS Professor,
       MAX(CASE occupation WHEN 'Singer' THEN name END) AS Singer,
       MAX(CASE occupation WHEN 'Actor' THEN name END) AS Actor
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM occupations o2
              WHERE o2.occupation = o.occupation AND
                    o2.name <= o.name
             ) as seqnum
      FROM occupations o
     ) o
GROUP BY seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't run in MySql, it runs in Oracle but the output is not the expected although almost. I think dense_rank is a better choice. On the other hand, we have an old version of MySql 5.x that doesn't admit windowing functions.

Comment: @Chema . . . It works.  I added a db<>fiddle.  This does use window functions.  They have been part of MySQL since early 2018 and your question doesn't specify the version.

Comment: Sorry, that's right. I will put the version in the post.

Comment: And that's right it works in MySql 8. With your approach I figured out the solution, may I append that to your post?

Comment: I have other solution that works, but yours is perfect!